# how to find out which culture's are supported in webproject -> Class CultureInfo?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, culture, cultureinfo

in my project i have two supported languages (german - "de", and english - "en")
I have resource files like: `Home.aspx.de.resx, Home.aspx.en.resx, Home.aspx.resx`

is it possible to read dynamicly which languages are supported in current webproject?
I dont want to validate it manually if they are just "de" and "en" like I do in follow code:

```
if (langName != "en" || langName != "de")
                    {
                        ci = new CultureInfo("en");

                        this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
                    }
```

I would like to get access of webproject languages like: `CultureInfo.(Who knows)..`.
If I will add a new language, f.E. "fr" I need again to add it manually into my logic.

my `Application_AcquireRequestState` method look like this:

```
protected void Application_AcquireRequestState(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (HttpContext.Current.Session != null)
            {
                //Create culture info object 
                CultureInfo ci = (CultureInfo)this.Session["Culture"];

                //Checking first if there is no value in session 
                //and set default language 
                //this can happen for first user's request
                if (ci == null)
                {
                    //Sets default culture to english invariant
                    string langName = "en";

                    //Try to get values from Accept lang HTTP header
                    if (HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages != null && HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages.Length != 0)
                    {
                        //Gets accepted list 
                        langName = HttpContext.Current.Request.UserLanguages[0].Substring(0, 2);

                    }
                    if (langName != "en" || langName != "de")
                    {
                        ci = new CultureInfo("en");

                        this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        ci = new CultureInfo(langName);
                        this.Session["Culture"] = ci;
                    }
                }

                //Finally setting culture for each request
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = ci;
                Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture(ci.Name);

            }
        }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Can you try to load the culture for the specified language and if it does not exist then load the default? I have done that in one of my web apps. You would use something like this in the base page.

```
        /// <summary>
    /// Initializes culture for the page
    /// </summary>
    [VersionChange( "6.1.34.89", "24/12/2009", "Custom Cultures added" )]
    protected override void InitializeCulture()
    {
        try
        {
            CultureInfo oCultureInfo;

            try
            {
                oCultureInfo = CultureInfo.CreateSpecificCulture( this.CurrentCustomCulture );
            }
            catch ( ArgumentException )
            {
                //Get culture info based on Great Britain
                CultureInfo cultureInfo = new CultureInfo( "en-GB" );
                RegionInfo regionInfo = new RegionInfo( cultureInfo.Name );

                CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder = new CultureAndRegionInfoBuilder( this.CurrentCustomCulture, CultureAndRegionModifiers.None );

                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromCultureInfo( cultureInfo );
                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.LoadDataFromRegionInfo( regionInfo );

                // Custom Changes
                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureEnglishName = this.CurrentCustomCulture;
                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.CultureNativeName = this.CurrentCustomCulture;

                cultureAndRegionInfoBuilder.Register();

                oCultureInfo = CultureInfo.GetCultureInfo( this.CurrentCustomCulture );
            }
            catch ( Exception )
            {
                throw;
            }

            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = oCultureInfo;
            Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentUICulture = oCultureInfo;

            Page.Culture = oCultureInfo.Name;
            Page.UICulture = oCultureInfo.Name;

            base.InitializeCulture();
        }
        catch ( Exception )
        {
            throw;
        }
    }
```

If you want to read available cultures from the server you can use

```
using System.Globalization;
```

CultureInfo.GetCultures( CultureTypes.AllCultures );

and CultureInfo.GetCultures( CultureTypes.UserCustomCulture );

Comment: exactly this i dodnt want to do. if you want to add spanish or french, you will need to add new language in you code manually. I want to read which languages are in resource files. and then if not exist load default language.

Comment: The code is first attempting to set the culture to this.CurrentCustomCulture which is a per user variable, you dont need to add any more code, just add new resource files for the new languages